# In react-navigation TabNavigator, how to setParams

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
const AppTabs = TabNavigator({
Home: {
  screen: FilmList,
},
FilmCinemaList: {
  screen: FilmCinemaList,
  path: 'cart',
},
FilmGoodsList: {
    screen: FilmGoodsList,
},
FilmMe: {
    screen: FilmMe,
},
})
```

when I click FilmCinemaList, i wanna pass a params. how to use setParams?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the params this way when rendering your AppTabs:

```
<AppTabs screenProps={{ FilmCinemaList: { ...yourParams } }}/>
```

And you can access them on FilmCinemaList by:

```
this.props.screenProps.FilmCinemaList
```

.

Comment: Works for me!, Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Through navigationOptions, what you have to do is to set the navigationOptions for the screen before pass it in the TabNavigator like the following:

```
FilmCinemaList.navigationOptions = {
 'param1':'value1';
};
const AppTabs = TabNavigator({
Home: {
  screen: FilmList,
},
FilmCinemaList: {
  screen: FilmCinemaList,
  path: 'cart',
},
FilmGoodsList: {
    screen: FilmGoodsList,
},
FilmMe: {
    screen: FilmMe,
},
})
```

And then you can access it

```
FilmCinemaList.navigationOptions.param1
```

When ever you need to.